# How to solve a network error with a WMS?

Tags: qgis, wms, data-source, corrupt

There is an error with a WebMapService I am using. The error message is depicted in the following image:

[image]

The properties of the file are shown in the image below.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this corrupted file? I am using QGIS version 3.4

Comment: Does the service otherwise display correctly?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean?

Comment: Is there content displayed on the map canvas?

Comment: No no content on the map canvas

Comment: Have you done any research at the providers website, whether there is a new URL or maintenance done or if the WMS has been taken offline?

Comment: I have, but I didnt originally download this file, so Im not too sure where on the website it came from. but still looking

Comment: You can see the server url in the screencapture: https://www.ukoilandgasdata.com/. The address does not answer.

Comment: https://www.ogauthority.co.uk/data-centre/ this is the redirected website link. However I am struggling to find the WMS file for surface installations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the ArcGIS FeatureServer address you need:
https://data.ogauthority.co.uk/arcgis/rest/services/OGA_Public_WGS84/OGA_Infrastructure_WGS84/FeatureServer/

Preview of the data that are present in this FeatureServer connection:
[image]

Preview of the data/extent:
[image]